# Regex match strings between asterisks

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var s = "*string1* *string2* *string3*";
```

I'm trying to create a regex which returns an array of the three strings between `*`

How can I do that? I tried using this but I'm not sure if it is correctly escaped

```
s.match("\*(.*)\*")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `lazy` quantifier `?` here and also escape `\`

Like this `\*(.*?)\*` [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH8lQ3/1)

Without using `lazy` quantifier you can do something like this.

`\*[^*]+\*` This will match a `*` `everything until a *` `*`. [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH8lQ3/2)

Use `\\` instead of `\` in actual code.

Comment: @noob Could you explain why the lazy quantifier `?` is necessary here?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt: As `*` are escaped they behave as literal and starting from literal `*` and matching greedily with `.*` until another literal `*` is found it will match upto end of string. To restrict that and match least number of  characters before a literal `*` regex should be made `lazy`.

Comment: @user2705585 How to prevent selecting those that are part of the whole word something like this " tes`*`ting `*`testing testing`*` " but should still be able to select the testing testing